# Avoid OutOfMemoryError for Bitmap.createScaledBitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am using following code to enlarge a image.

```
bmp=new BitmapFactory().decodeFile(util.getPathFromUri(tempFile));
Bitmap scaledBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, newWidth, newHeight, true); //Line 2
ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
scaledBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
bmp.recycle();
bmp=null;
OutputStream out;
out = new FileOutputStream(util.getTempFileName());
bos.writeTo(out);
bos.flush();
```

But sometimes OutOfMemoryError occurs at line 2 and app crashes, I tried enclosing this code within try-catch but still my app crashes as only exceptions are caught by try-catch, also `createScaledBitmap()` functions only throws `IllegalArgumentException`.
Since, I don't want to display image therefore I don't need ot scale it down(as I saw in other Questions in SOF).
So, How can I pre-detect that OutOfMemoryError will occur if I use that (newWidth, newHeight). Is there any way to calculate bytes required by Bitmap of (newWidth, newHeight) in memory and max available memory that can be allocated to bitmap?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inSampleSize = 1;
options.inScaled = false;
options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
options.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
options.inScreenDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
new BitmapFactory().decodeFile(util.getPathFromUri(tempFile),options);
```

Comment: Till now decode function is working fine. I get error in createScaledBitmap() function. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid java.lang.OutOfMemory exceptions, check the dimensions of a bitmap before decoding it, unless you absolutely trust the source to provide you with predictably sized image data that comfortably fits within the available memory. For more details see [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to resize your bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmpResizeResult = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmapWantToResize, width, height);
```